# SQL query for finding all records with Table Name from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three table Table1,Table2,Table3. Each table contains Column "Comments". So i want to find the records with table name.

For Example:

**Table1**

```
Id         Comments

98         test

99         test

100        attach
```

**Table2**

```
Id    Comments 

101   test

102   test

103   module
```

**Table3**

```
Id    Comments

111   test

112   test

113   exist
```

If i say `select * from Table1,Table2,Table3 where comments like '%test%'`

Result should be like this :

```
Id      Table    Comments

98      Table1   test

99      Table1   test

101     Table2   test

102     Table2   test

111     Table3   test

112     Table3   test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT Id, 'Table1' AS Table, Comments
FROM Table1
WHERE Comments LIKE '%test%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, 'Table2' AS Table, Comments
FROM Table2
WHERE Comments LIKE '%test%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, 'Table3' AS Table, Comments
FROM Table3
WHERE Comments LIKE '%test%`
```

Comment: will it impact the performance ? Actually i have thousands of records nearly 1 lakh

Comment: Your question is only half-written.  Will it affect the performance as compared to what?  If you have an alternative, we can discuss the performance.  I don't see a way out of querying the three tables.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim Biegeleisen